# How to left-adjust the horizontal spacing of a paragraph from a second line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

firstly the code is follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{(1)} - \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows:
[image]
I want the sentences from the second line to the last line in the paragraph to start at the position directly below the `-` sign in the first line.

I tried using `\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=\parindent\rightmargin=0pt}` but couldn't quite get it right. Any tip or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should happen when the number get two-digits? Is the paragraph indented more? Think about the transition between 9 and 10...

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. Then I would use the number 01 instead of just 1 to make sure lines are consistently aligned. I would like to know if there is any general algorithm to start the setences from the second line at the position of my choice. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use an `enumerate` environment? Unrelated: typographically, you should use an `endash` (` –`) or an `emdash` (`—`), not a simple dash, which is used for hyphenation.

Comment: You could use `\hangindent`, although in this case it might be easier to set `\leftskip` and use `\llap{\mbox{(1) }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,
            bindingoffset=0.2in,
            hmargin=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
    \begin{enumerate}[\textbf{(1)}]
    \item - \lipsum[1]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this great package. I encountered only one problem regarding this and opened another post to solve it. Could you have a look if you could solve it? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370017/how-to-remove-vertical-space-created-when-inserting-environments-inside-proof-en

Answer (score 0):

One idea, if the shift is fixed:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
    \leavevmode\llap{\textbf{(1)} }- \lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

This is aligned as a `quote`, and the number and the following space is typeset hanging outside --- aligning at the start of the hyphen.

The trick is using `\leavevmode` to start a paragraph, and then the command `\llap` will typeset it's content "hiding" the size and extending it to the left --- so that for LaTeX is a zero width box.

[image]

If you do not want the right margin indent that come with `quote`, you can also do (enclosed by `{` and `}` to make the changes local):

```
{\parindent=0pt
\leavevmode\hangindent=2cm\hangafter=0\llap{\textbf{(1)} }- \lipsum[1]

}
```

which will start the paragraph 2cm to the right for every line and then do the same trick with the number, `\llap`ed to stick out to the left.

Or maybe, instead of reinventing the whell, use the [`hang`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hang?lang=en) or [`hanging`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hanging?lang=en) packages...

Comment: I truly appreciate your wonderful enlightment, I get exactly what I want when I use `hangindent=0cm` except for the (1) sticking out to the left margin. Could you possibly fix this? Thank you so much again.

Comment: I think `enumeration` package sort of gives me what I want except when I insert it into a proof or theorem it generates extra space. I highly appreciate your efforts to help me. Thank you so much.